# How to filter products by category in Prestashop Web Service

Tags: json, rest, web, prestashop

I need help listing XML output of product details filtered by category.

Using the restful web services of prestashop, you can list all products with:

http://yourshop.com/api/products/?display=full

You can also list all of product id's within a category with:

http://yourshop.com/api/categories/?display=full

I am using this for an ios app, and the trouble is that i cant list products details from category [x] without making multiple calls to the api.

`api/products/?display=full&filter[category]=[x]` does not work.

As category here is an associative array.  (array within array).

What would be the best way to get a list of products from category x?

Seems like a simple request?

Comment: @Eirenaios The above is just a sample link of prestashop restful api, obvisouly yourshop.com would just be whatever your domain is.

Comment: @HussainHusaini did you find any solution to it. I am also facing the same issue. PS returns all the categories be it sub-category also as main.

Answer (score 0):

It think you can filter your products with **id_category_default**

`api/products/?display=full&filter[id_category_default]=[x]`

In my case **id_category_default=5** and **id_category_default=7** listing products based on category.

Comment: The problem with id_category_default, is that it can't select the second category if a product has multiple categories :(

Comment: yep, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

with this link you can get all products that their category is YOURCATID

http://yourshop.com/api/categories/?display=full&filter[id]=[YOURCATID]

in the inner part of JSON file you can see the products ID

Comment: Ok, you get the product's IDs. So how do you get the full products now? If you propose saving the IDs and then calling `http://yourshop.com/api/products?display=full&filter[id]=[1|3|4...etc]` I'll just answer you: **HTTP Error 414: URI too long** :/

Comment: This is not the right solution, this will return lots of IDs and you will have to make a request for each one. Further, it returns inactive products too